# How to tackle checked event in DataGrid checkboxs

Tags: c#, asp.net, pocketpc, handheld

I need to fill a DataGrid with DataTable object as DataSource. Its perfect, I can do this but, I stuck with CheckBox requirement in each Row. I know DataGridView provides DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn but, I want the same for DataGrid.

I got a solution, something like this -

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Books");

        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ISBN", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Price", typeof(System.Int32));
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Author", typeof(System.String));

        DataColumn dcSelectToDelete = new DataColumn("Select");
        dcSelectToDelete.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
        dcSelectToDelete.DefaultValue = false;

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
        dt.Columns.Add(dcSelectToDelete);

        drd.DataSource = dt;
```

But I am not sure for the correctness of this code.Also If it works, I dont know, How to tackle Checked event of checkBoxes.

Kindly suggest the correct solution for DataGrid (Not DataGridView).

If I will fill the datatable by certain list. How will I dynamically add CheckBox in each column?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for you to use `DataGrid` instead of `GridView` which is certainly better and more capable conrtrol?

Regardless, to show Check Box in DataGrid, you need to use [TemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn.aspx). In case, you are using auto generation of columns then you need to switch if off and instead specify all columns manually. For example,

```
<asp:DataGrid id="MyDataGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ... >
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name"/>
       <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="ISBN" DataField="ISBN"/>
       ...
       <asp:TemplateColumn>
          <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectRow" runat="server" 
                Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Select") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
   </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

The data-table code would remain same as you have posted - the checked property of check-box is set as per the value in select column.

Comment: I know this method, but I am developing the application for Handheld device, which doesn't support GridView

Comment: @RTRokzzz, you had tagged your question with ASP.NET tag which I suspect is incorrect. My answer is useful for ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use DataGridTemplateColumn (as in WPF DataGrid) and within it put a check box with Checked and UnChecked events or whatever event then handle this in the code behind.
e.g in WPF add within DataGrid.Columns

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  >
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelect" Checked="chkSelect_Checked" Unchecked="chkSelect_Unchecked" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Also, you have not specified technology as WPF, ASP or other.

Comment: It is ASP.net, C# Handheld application (Pocket PC). It doesn't support above feature. All should be done in backend.